# OGRE: Non-Standard Resolution

Tags: ogre

I am using OGRE to make a re-rendering of the film, which has a wide aspect ratio (around 1.85). The OGRE dialog seems to be showing the standard full screen resolution by default (800/600, 1024/768, etc.), but those obviously have aspect ratios of 1.333 or around that. But as long as I am not running full screen mode, why should I be restricted to these screen sizes only?

I can definitely change the viewport size, but that would make it difficult for me to generate the video later.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no any restrictions for using non standard (4:3) aspect ratio screen resolution in Ogre. Default OGRE configuration window just show list of defaults resolution.
But if you need other screen side you should create it from the code directly depending on the dimensions of your input video.